# Python Function returning null

Tags: python

```
def counter(number,count):
    if (number!=1 and number%2==0):
        a=number/2
        count=count+1
        counter(a,count)
    elif (number!=1 and number%2!=0):
        a=3*(number)+1
        count=count+1
        counter(a,count)        
    else:
        print count
        return count

z=counter(13,0)
print z
```

`count` is evaluated to `9` and it does print it, but won't return it? Says `None` when printing 'z'

Answer (score 3):

You are ignoring the recursive calls; add `return` statements where you call `counter()` *in `counter` itself*:

```
def counter(number,count):
    if (number!=1 and number%2==0):
        a=number/2
        count=count+1
        return counter(a,count)
    elif (number!=1 and number%2!=0):
        a=3*(number)+1
        count=count+1
        return counter(a,count)        
    else:
        print count
        return count
```

Recursive calls are just like any other function call, if you don't do anything with the return value it is just discarded. Recursive calls don't magically pass on their result to the outermost call.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the result of recursion.

```
return counter(a,count)
```